# Installing Postgis 2.2.0 on Windows?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, installation, windows

I'm trying to get the newest version of Postgis (2.2.0) up and running with Postgres 9.4.

I'm using Windows and the only installation manuels I found, are Linux-only.

Can anybody point me in the direction of a useful Windows-installer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just did it yesterday :-) so its fresh .. copy the zip file from:

64Bits 
pg 9.2> http://winnie.postgis.net/download/windows/pg92/buildbot/postgis-pg92-binaries-2.2.0w64gcc48.zip

pg 9.3> http://winnie.postgis.net/download/windows/pg93/buildbot/postgis-pg93-binaries-2.2.0w64gcc48.zip

32Bits 
pg 9.2> http://winnie.postgis.net/download/windows/pg92/buildbot/postgis-pg92-binaries-2.2.0w32gcc481.zip

pg 9.3> http://winnie.postgis.net/download/windows/pg93/buildbot/postgis-pg93-binaries-2.2.0w32gcc481.zip

Unzip the file - read the README.txt file , it will tell you to copy files and folders that mirror you actual installation of Postgres folder , its  like that copy files and overwrite the ones needed. Then remove old postgis extension installed in your databases, you cant have multiple Postgis versions installed.
And hopefully should be it. Read the README file .

Comment: Thanks Jorge for the quick response!
I had to install postgres 9.2.14 in order to make it work, but it seems to be working now. Thanks!

Comment: FWIW: there is lots of discussion going on on PostGIS dev https://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/postgis-devel/2015-October/date.html , so might have another 2.2.1 in another 2 weeks.  mostly to fix a topology regression, and if SFCGAL fixes issue upsteam (that jvidinha noted), I'll have a new SFCGAL as soon as they have a fix..  Thanks for testing, both of you :).